# Integer concatenation with macro

Tags: console, integer, basic, freebasic

How to concatenate integer correctly with macro ?
I must call it twice here because i can't add something after ","(error)

```
#define concat(a,b,c) a##b##c
dim as integer a=10,b=20,c=30,d
d = a concat(*100+,,)b
d = d concat(*100+,,)c
?d  'output = 102030
sleep
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution from freebasic forum

```
#define concat(a,b,c)  (((a)*100+(b))*100+(c))
dim as integer a=10,b=20,c=30,d
d = concat(a,b,c)
?d  'output = 102030
sleep
```

Comment: This won't work in all cases. If c is 300 then you'll get 1002300 instead of 10020300. See my answer if you need something more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define concat(a,b,c) val(str(a)+str(b)+str(c))
```